# In what order are messages and runnables handled by a Handler?

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, message, runnable

From reading the documentation of [`Handler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), I get the idea that both messages **and** runnables are posted onto the same message queue of the thread associated with that Handler.

My question is, are they both processed in the order they are posted/sent?

For example, imagine I have a handler *myHandler* and I do the following:

```
myHandler.post(runnable1);
myHandler.sendMessage(message1);
myHandler.post(runnable2);
myHandler.sendMessage(message2);
```

In what order would these runnables and messages be processed?

Would each of them be processed in the same order as they were posted/sent? Are messages processed separately from runnables? Or is it more complicated, like messages given a higher priority than runnables?